# WordPress Migration from Windows to Linux, Unable to Login to Staging Sites

Tags: linux, wordpress, windows, migration

I am working to migrate a clients WP site from Windows to Linux, and I am having an issue logging into their DEV and PROD site after successfully migrating UAT to the new servers.

A little background to uncomplicate this, they have three sites (DEV/UAT/and PROD) on a Windows server that are currently still viewable to the public.

The new Linux servers, since the migrations have not yet been completed, are only accessible by the IP address. As of now, I have been able to successfully migrate the UAT site from the old servers to the new servers, using WP All in One Migration. I am able to log into the UAT instance, make changes, updates, etc. However, when I try to log into the DEV and PROD instances on the new servers, I am getting an error that the WP username/email does not exist, so I am unable to complete the migration for the remaining two instances. I am still able to log into the old Windows servers and make changes, but not the new servers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You likely did not get a usable full copy of the database. When you migrate WordPress around, the files on the server is only a small portion of the data you need. You MUST get copies of everything in the database as well or the site will not function! Do a dump of the database and then restore it on your DEV/UAT database node. You may need to jump through some hoops to change the URL that is embedded in the database as well for the sites to function properly as well. It's a PITA, but once you get the hang of it, you can script it and take the human out of the loop. I used to do this with a script that ran the DB search and replace statements.

As an alternative, you can add a user (even an administrator) to WordPress using only the database. Can be handy in some situations ...

INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_status`, `d isplay_name`) VALUES ('1000', 'usernamefornewuser', MD5('plaintextnewuserpassword'), 'usernameforyournewuser', 'newuseremail@somenewuseremaildomain.com', '0', 'The New User I just created');

INSERT INTO  `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '1000', 'wp_ca
pabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}');

INSERT INTO  `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '1000', 'wp_us
er_level', '10');

There are some values you will have to change however I have personally used these MySQL snippets with WordPress for many, many moons (years!).

Comment: thank you for the clarification! So I took a full backup from the old servers from the All in One Migration plugin and imported that into the new servers, but these do not contain the databases, is basically my issue?

Comment: The All in One Migration plugin will grab the database export, all the files from the webroot and make those easily transportable. The one gotcha I see with this is the settings for the database in wp_config.php. In All the migrations I have seen, they almost never have the same database hostname and credentials. Verify that you have made this adjustment for your new DB backend.